# How to submit the IOS app to app store after it was rejected by the app store review team?

Tags: ios, app-store

Recently I submitted an IOS app to the app store and they reject the app because of some issues. Now I fix all those issues and I need to resubmit the app. **What are the steps to resubmit the app again for the review?**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resubmit the app for review follow the below steps:

1. Change/correct the things what apple mentioned while rejecting.
2. Change the build version number.
3. Then upload the new archive build to app store, in the itunes
   connect it takes some time (approx - 20 - 30 min) for reflecting the
   new build.

You can check the status of the app in your itunes connect account. login to your account and select your app, in the app description page select **Activity** section from the top options panel and select the left side panel options like All builds, app store versions etc..

Comment: I submit the new IPA before 5 hours ago, no new build is showing in the Build section

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should press that button by selecting the new IPA that you have uploaded and proceed to allow them to review again. As the application is binary rejected so, you have to upload new IPA with the fixes they have suggested. if it is something related to metadata then you only have to fix the description and resubmit.

Hope it helps.